# Specific cURL usage and weird bug

Tags: php, curl, cookies, http-status-code-302

I'm using cURL with PHP to connect to my University admin website to provide a mobile-user-friendly interface in order to access my informations, such as grades. So basically I just have a form in which I put the login informations and my code uses these credentials to connect to the admin website and returns the wanted informations that I show in a mobile way.

The problem is that the connection doesn't work and I get a blank page excepted when I log on my account from any other device before attempting to connect with my program. That is, if for example this morning I accessed my account normally (and log out since), my code will work, but tomorrow it won't unless I access first normally my account.

I've been studying the connection process with Chrome's development tool again and again and I don't know where I'm wrong. The only suspicion I have is that the first page loaded with the credentials sent returns a 302 FOUND and the redirection is not applied by cURL, but the first page returns a connexion cookie, which I assumed was the only thing needed to be log in correctly. I think maybe the insertion of the created cookie into the server's database should be done on the second page in order for this one to be accepted next...

Here is my code:

```
$lien = 'https://isa.epfl.ch/imoniteur_ISAP/!logins.tryToConnect';

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['passwd'];
$postfields = array(
    'ww_x_username' => $login,
    'ww_x_password' => $password,
    'ww_x_urlAppelant' => ''
);

$path_cookie = 'cookie.txt';
if (!file_exists(realpath($path_cookie))) touch($path_cookie);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $lien);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($path_cookie));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$host = array(
    0 => 'Host: '. parse_url("http://isa.epfl.ch", PHP_URL_HOST),
    1 => 'Referer: https://isa.epfl.ch/imoniteur_ISAP/!logins.htm',
    2 => 'Origin: https://isa.epfl.ch'
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $host);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13');

$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
unset($curl);
```

I hope someone could help me! I'll be happy to give more precisions if necessary!
Thanks
Romain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue! It was pretty simple, maybe so simple that I didn't see the solution earlier...
If someone wants more explanation, I'll be happy to give it.